# Azure Cosmos Db Emulator starting but never start

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use Azure Cosmos Db Emulator for about 1 year now and it’s the 3de time it sudently stop working.

The only way i found for resolve the problem was to do a complete re-install of windows 10 …

My configuration :

- Windows 10 Pro
- Administrator privilege
- Domain link to AAD
- Antivirus software : ESET Endpoint antivirus 9.1.2051.0
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz
- 32 Go of RAM
- All my software installed on C :

I try this in command prompt (as Administrator) :

1. Clear performance counter before start

- `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /shutdown`
- `lodctr /R`  (2 time to be sure)
- `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe`

Result :

- The notification for « Starting » show up
- A dump file is create in `AppData/Local/CrashDumps`
- The notification that the emulator is « start » never come
- The web page never open

2. Uninstall – re-install

- `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /shutdown`
- Delete folder `AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator`
- Uninstall Cosmos Db Emulator
- Delete folder `C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`
- Restart the computer
- Install last app version : `azure-cosmosdb-emulator-2.14.9-3c8bff92.msi`
- Check for start the emulator after install end

Result :

- Same result than 1)

3. Start trace

```
-   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /shutdown
-   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /startwprtraces
-   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe
-   [wait for 1 minute]
-   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /stopwprtraces
-   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /shutdown
```

Result :

- The notification for « Starting » show up
- A dump file is create in `AppData/Local/CrashDumps`
- Until the 1 minute of waiting , a dump file was created for about every 20/30s
- When i execute `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /stopwprtraces`, a `docdbemulator_001.etl` was created in `C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`
- The notification that the emulator is « start » never come
- The web page never open

I try to read the dump file with WinDbg.exe and i found this error message :

```
CLR_EXCEPTION_System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException_80131577_Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.dll!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.Service.WindowsFabricConfigurationProvider.GetValue
```

And the stack trace was :

```
00000085`583feb40 00007ffe`49323302 Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Common!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.Service.WindowsFabricConfigurationProvider.GetValue+0x52
00000085`583feb80 00007ffe`493230cb Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Common!Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.CrashDump.Register+0xdb
00000085`583febf0 00007ffe`48f673ee Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Compute_Host_ServiceFabric_EntryPoint!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.CosmosDBGatewayInit+0x56e
00000085`583fecf0 00007ffe`48f51465 Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Compute_Host_ServiceFabric_EntryPoint!Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.Main+0x295
```

In windows logs I found the same error description (in french):

```
Application : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.exe Version du Framework : v4.0.30319 Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée. Informations sur l'exception : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException à Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.Service.WindowsFabricConfigurationProvider.GetValue(System.String) à Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.CrashDump.Register(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Core.IConfigurationProvider) à Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.CosmosDBGatewayInit(System.Fabric.CodePackageActivationContext, System.String) à Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.Main(System.String[])
```

And

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.exe
            2.14.0.0
            bc4d0da5
            KERNELBASE.dll
            10.0.19041.1889
            e9ede6d6
            e0434352
            0000000000034fd9
            4360
            01d8b7ac99b3d711
            C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\CosmosGatewayService\CosmosGatewayService.Code\EP\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.exe
            C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
            01134c47-5efa-4d7a-a243-15af35536df0
```

Comment: I think this could be related to either firewall or environment changes. That said why don't you use the docker version of it?

Comment: think for your reply, I have been thinking about an antivirus or firewall pb, but i try to un install both and reinstall cosmos db emulator  but the pb stay the same. For the moment the docker is not convenient for my use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I found that Cosmos Db create 3 Security Groups that are not delete on uninstall.

I delete all 3 and remove all registry reference on each. (searching for Cosmos Db and DocDb)

Now when i reinstall all work properly !

Thanks you David for your help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, which security groups are you reffering to? Local Security Policy or something else?

Comment: You can found the 3 security groups in the groups and users parameter

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above, the security groups are under Computer management

- DocDbGatewayService
- DocDBMasterService
- DocDbServerService

This still didn't clear it for me, I did find the following in the Event Log

> Application:
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
> due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.Service.WindowsFabricConfigurationProvider.GetValue(System.String)
> at
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common.CrashDump.Register(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>,
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Core.IConfigurationProvider)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.CosmosDBGatewayInit(System.Fabric.CodePackageActivationContext,
> System.String)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Compute.Host.ServiceFabric.EntryPoint.EntryPoint.Main(System.String[])

And I managed to clear the issue with the following command

**netsh http add iplisten ipaddress:0.0.0.0**

This was taken from this thread - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6788